# Would this corrupt the stack using a local variable?

Tags: c++, std

In my class I have a member

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > mEnvironment;
```

Now I wrote a function which loads this vector with the process environment as key/value pairs. I don't need to access the members, so I don't use a map, and figured that a vector would be better, as I only iterate over it.

```
void Environment::setEnvironment(char const *oEnvironment[])
{
    mEnvironment.clear();
    if(oEnvironment == NULL)
        return;

    std::string name;
    std::string value;
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> entry;
    for(const char **envp = oEnvironment; *envp != NULL; envp++)
    {
        const char *env = *envp;
        name.clear();
        value.clear();

        for(env = *envp; *env != 0; env++)
        {
            if(*env == '=')
            {
                env++;
                break;
            }

            name += *env;
        }

        value = env;

        entry = std::make_pair(name, value);
        mEnvironment.push_back(entry);
    }
}
```

Since the variable `entry` is local, I wonder what happens with the `push_back(entry)` when the function goes out of scope. will the objects, I put into the vector, persist, or will the destructor be called? Or even worse, will it simpley be overwritten or do I have to create a new pair object in the loop instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing bad will happen, as the vector makes a copy of the pair (and each of the two strings in it).

To back this up, here is the relevant quote from the Standard (C++11, §23.2.3, in the big table on page 738 of the official edition):

> `a.push_back(t)` [...] Appends a copy of `t` // *Requires:* `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` into `X`.

Here, `X` stands for the vector type, and `t` for an lvalue or constant rvalue of type `T`, which is the type of the member elements. So this applies to your case. (If the pair were to be created on the fly, i.e. inside the `push_back(...)` function call, you'd have a temporary rvalue, which means a different table row would apply and you'd get a move instead of a copy, but there would still not be any problems.)

A vector stores copies of its elements. (The only danger exists when you have a vector whose element types are defined as a pointer type, or some struct or class that has pointer members. The vector then, of course, makes copies only of the pointers, not deep copies of the content; or in the case of a struct or class type, it makes copies as defined by the copy constructor of that data type. But for a `std::pair` of `std::string`, all will work as expected.)

Comment: Thanks. I was unsure what the classes really do, but I figured, that it doesn't make sense if they would not create a copy. wanted to make sure though. :)